# jquery escape square brackets to select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors, escaping

Consider a input element

```
<input id="meta[152][value]" type="text" />
```

Here the input field is **dynamically** generated. I need to select that field. So I used,

```
alert($('#meta[152][value]').val());
```

But this seems to be invalid. After searching I found, that the "square brackets" need to be escaped like `#meta\\[152\\]\\[value\\]`

So how to do that ?
I currently use this code,

```
var id = "#meta[152][value]" // (I get this value by another method) I need the escaping to be done here. So that i can use as
```

/** I need the value of id to be escaped using regex,replace or any other method
    to get #meta\[152\]\[value\] 
    and not manually **/

```
alert($(id).val());
```

Your suggestions will be helpful !

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between these different ways to escape square brackets inside jQuery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573178/what-is-the-difference-between-these-different-ways-to-escape-square-brackets-in)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should work:

```
alert($('#meta\[152\]\[value\]').val());
```

or

```
var id = "#meta\[152\]\[value\]";
alert($(id).val());
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/grGcD/)

**Conversion Function:**

```
function ConvertValue(id)
{
    var test = id.replace(/[[]/g,'\\\\[');
    return "#" + test.replace(/]/g,'\\\\]'); 
}
```

**[Conversion Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KqvMM/6)**

Comment: thanks for the try.. but i just gave id = "#meta[152][value]" as an example and i cannot directly change it . It need to be changed using regex or replace

Comment: Aakash, I added a conversion function to convert your id value into the value that you would need to use a selector. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Updated the function and added an Example, hope this helps. You should be able to pass the id into it and it should return the proper selector for you.

Comment: when i use the return value, i cannot select the element !! what will be the reason ? http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/KqvMM/3/

Comment: If you use the return function that returns '#YourTestValue', then to select that using jQuery you could simply take that return value and place it in a selector, as such : $("#YourTestValue") to select that element

Comment: Did that, but not working, see the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/KqvMM/3/

Comment: but not able to get the value !! after selecting the element !! sorry for too many questions

Comment: Hmm - that is strange. I'm not sure why that is happening. I'll look into it some more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5693/discussion-between-aakash-chakravarthy-and-rionmonster)

Answer (score 6):

If you feel more comfortable without escaping you also use the attributes selector and search for the element with that id like this: `$("[id='meta[152][value]']")`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is just to use the regular getElementById, which requires no escaping:

```
document.getElementById("meta[152][value]").value;
```

Comment: And don't forget to 
a) remove the leading hash (#)
b) add the trailing .value

Answer (score 1):

this shoudl work for you, you almost had it:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var id = "#meta\\[152\\]\\[value\\]";
        alert($(id).val()); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, just put the escaped value right in your string.

```
var id = "#meta\\[152\\]\\[value\\]";
```

[See it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gt9ZQ/)

Comment: thanks for the try.. but i just gave id = "#meta[152][value]" as an example and i cannot directly change it . It need to be changed using regex or replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`_.escapeRegExp`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#escapeRegExp) method from the Lodash library.

```js
console.log($('#' + _.escapeRegExp('meta[152][value]')).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<input id="meta[152][value]" type="text" value='Test' />
```