# How to allow user to add another input row that submits to a php file

Tags: php, jquery

I made a simple GPA (grade point average) calculator and I am just playing around with some stuff and would really like to know how to allow the user to add rows as they please. The best example that I could find of someone doing this is at this website: http://gpacalculator.net/high-school-gpa-calculator/

I think I might understand when the user clicks the button, a jquery function could add a row but how do i get it so the name of the input element is different every time someone adds a row. How will the php file know the name of the $_POST['someName'].

So question in short: How do I add a row using jquery, and then submit that form to a php file so it is different than the pre-made rows.

Just in case you need to know, I store the values that are sent to the php file in variables. and then enter them into the formula that calculates the GPA.

EDIT HERE IS CODE FOR TABLE:

```
<table>
    <form id = "myform" name = "myform" method = "POST" action = "">
        <tr> 
            <th> Grade in test </th> 
            <th> Weight of grade </th> <br />
         </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade1" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight1"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade2" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight2"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade3" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight3"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade4" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight4"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade5" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight5"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade6" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight6"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade7" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight7"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade8" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight8"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade9" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight9"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade10" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight10"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade11" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight11"  /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade12" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight12"  /> </td> </tr>

<tr> 
  <td> <div id = "submitButton">
          <input type = "submit" value = "SUBMIT"  style = " font-family:'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; padding: 10px;border: none; color: white; background-color: #0499ff; width: 100%; font-size: 13px; border-radius: 5px;""/></div></td> <td> <input type = "reset"  /> </td></tr>

    </form>
    </table>
     <div id = "results2"></div>
</div>
```

AND THEN THE CODE IN PHP FILE CUT DOWN TO THE INITIAL VARIABLES:

```
/* GRADES VARS */
$grade1 = $_POST['grade1'];
$grade2 = $_POST['grade2'];
$grade3 = $_POST['grade3'];
$grade4 = $_POST['grade4'];
$grade5 = $_POST['grade5'];
$grade6 = $_POST['grade6'];
$grade7 = $_POST['grade7'];
$grade8 = $_POST['grade8'];
$grade9 = $_POST['grade9'];
$grade10 = $_POST['grade10'];
$grade11 = $_POST['grade11'];
$grade12 = $_POST['grade12'];


/* GRADE WEIGHT VARS */
$weight1 = $_POST['weight1'];
$weight2 = $_POST['weight2'];
$weight3 = $_POST['weight3'];
$weight4 = $_POST['weight4'];
$weight5 = $_POST['weight5'];
$weight6 = $_POST['weight6'];
$weight7 = $_POST['weight7'];
$weight8 = $_POST['weight8'];
$weight9 = $_POST['weight9'];
$weight10 = $_POST['weight10'];
$weight11 = $_POST['weight11'];
$weight12 = $_POST['weight12'];
```

THANKS!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See the [FAQ], please.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet... I have no clue how I would go about making a jquery function that would set up a whole new row of inputs with different names each time... I have tried some things for a couple of days now but quickly erased them knowing that they weren't even close

Comment: If you do a little digging in resource tab (chrome) you can find just what it does and modify it towards your needs.

Comment: I made one for fun, it's http://gpacal.com. You can look at the source, it's not entirely finished but I just made it for friends and stuff to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically you need to use field names as an array so take this example:

```
<input type="text" name="someName[]" value="0" />
<input type="text" name="someName[]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="someName[]" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="someName[]" value="6" />
```

When you do a for submit and post the values to the server you will be able to access them with PHP as an array like so:

```
echo $_POST['someName'][0]; // outputs 0
echo $_POST['someName'][1]; // outputs 2
echo $_POST['someName'][2]; // outputs 4
echo $_POST['someName'][3]; // outputs 6
```

Now since you won't know how many rows there are you can loop over it:

```
foreach($_POST['someName'] as $someName){
    echo $someName; //will output the value 0/2/4/6 depending on the iteration
}
```

When adding the button with javascript you just need to make sure the name is the same and with brackets:

```
$('#addButton').click(function(){
    $('.container').append('<input type="text" name="someName[]" value="someNumber" />');
});
```

As long as you have that and inputs are inside of form tag that can be submitted this will work.

**Edit** so based on the code you added to your initial answer I would recommend taking advantage of arrays in PHP.

So lets say you use the inputs like I explained above (by the way this can be used on any HTML element that can be posted to the backend [checkboxes, inputs, textareas, selects, etc...]).  You could do this:

```
$grades = array();
foreach($_POST['grade'] as $g){
    $grades[] = $g; // add grade from each input to the array
}

// then you can manipulate the data through looping through it.
foreach($grades as $grade){
    // do something here with each grade...whether it be manipulating it
    // or adding it another array with some changes whatever.
}
```

This should allow you to clean up your code and you can do the same thing with your weights.

Answer (score -1):

::::::::EDIT AFTER LOOKING AT CODE::::::::

You are going about this all wrong with you're code. HOWEVER if you'd like to get it working using the existing code try something like this:

change

```
<tr> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade12" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight12"  /> </td> </tr>
```

to

```
<tr id="last"> <td><input type = "text" name = "grade12" /> </td> <td> <input type = "text" name = "weight12"  /> </td> </tr>
```

then jQuery would look something like this:

```
$("#add-button").click(function() {
      $('#last').append("<tr><td><input type = \"text\" name = \"customgrades[\]\" /> </td> <td> <input type = \"text\" name = \"customweight[\]\"  /> </td> </tr>");
    });
```

then do a button or link
Add a grade

Once you submit the form, on the php side of things

```
$_REQUEST[customgrades];
$_REQUEST[customweight];
```

OR if your elitist friend on the internet want's to chastise you for using $_REQUEST even though in this application there is no reason why you can't use it you can use:

```
$_POST[customgrades];
$_POST[customweight];
```

Those two variables will hold arrays with the associated data.

Comment: Don't use $_REQUEST, you should know what you are expecting on the backend and should use that.  What if someone set the $_GET to be customGrades and it over wrote the post variables with something malicious?

YOU should never use $_REQUEST and you shouldn't use it in example code either.

Comment: Also whats with escaping the brackets in the javascript?  What you really need to be escaping is the double quotes you put for the input.  Its going to end the string earlier than expected (As you can see in the syntax highlighter where it goes from red to black).  You should use single quotes for holding the string here, and use double quotes for the attributes on the input.  Then no escaping is needed (not even the brackets).

Comment: One final criticism, your first 2 examples are identical...your not changing anything.

Comment: Firstly, in this specific application, there is no reason he can't use $_REQUEST... Secondly: yes my escape was in the wrong area good catch, however you still need to escape the [] in jQuery... Thirdly: I gave him a proper example for his existing code...Lastly

Comment: No you don't, if the brackets are in a string it treats them as standard characters, not as an array literal.

Comment: Go ahead and try this code WITHOUT escaping the brackets $('form').append('<input type="hidden" value="'+value+'" name="'+this.id+'[\]">');

Comment: You need to escape "[]" in append, if you don't you will not get an HTML array. Give it a try and post your results. Also enjoy this post on what im talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404037/jquery-escape-square-brackets-to-select-element

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22795/discussion-between-jefffan24-and-hydra-io)