# Jquery show/hide div script broken by HTML -> PHP Arrays, any workaround?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am working on a huge multi page form with multiple sub sections and answer dependent sub-questions.

I am using JQuery to show/hide divs based on SELECT values which works perfectly. However when it comes to handling the data I would like to be able to break down the POST values by page.

I could do this by using the following syntax in my fields

```
<label>What is the Reference?</label>
    <input type="text" name="[title][0][Reference]" value="<?php echo $out['Reference']?>" /><img src="images/hint.png" class="hint" title="Edit me!!" /><br />
```

and then calling an if else on $_POST['title'] and using a iterative function to handle the database side of things.

However I'm finding that if I do this it breaks my Jquery Show/Hide div, the functionality of which is integral to the form (which has 100's of questions reading into many seperate tables).

This is the Jquery script, is there anyway to enhance/change it to allow me to use HTML->PHP arrays?

```
// Works like this
$('#Reference').change(function () {
    var whatToShow = $('#Reference').val();

    $('div[class^=divarea-]').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.divarea-' + whatToShow).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

This doesnt work, presumably the brackets are interferring but I don't know how to escape stuff in Java.

```
// Doesnt work
$('#[title][0][Reference]').change(function () {
    var whatToShow = $('#[title][0][Reference]').val();

    $('div[class^=divarea-]').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.divarea-' + whatToShow).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: Just a thought, does this char make any difference? '^'

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Sorry I should have done some more checking, I just needed to use \ in front of each square bracket, works fine now.

[This question was very useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404037/jquery-escape-square-brackets-to-select-element)