# jQuery Syntax error, unrecognized expression - Using {

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery with SharePoint 2013, and have to get the table Id to add an attribute.
The table Id is

```
{44C80A95-F3E4-40DA-9A97-50CADFFFED61}-{DD02CEA7-CC2B-4E4A-A725-86E82C6D11FC}
```

When I use:

```
jQuery("#{44C80A95-F3E4-40DA-9A97-50CADFFFED61}-{DD02CEA7-CC2B-4E4A-A725-86E82C6D11FC}").attr("width","100%");
```

It gives me this erro:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{44C80A95-F3E4-40DA-9A97-50CADFFFED61}-{DD02CEA7-CC2B-4E4A-A725-86E82C6D11FC}
```

The problem is with the "{".

How to solve this problem?

Comment: welp, 2 peeps already beat me to the answer, but they're spot on. This is just one more reason I ***HATE*** Sharepoint and will **NEVER** take a contract using it EVER again! You can check my blog for one of the craziest issues I ever saw -> http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-reset-digital-signature-on.html <- Couldn't find a single working solution online. I reference it here in case you ever come across the same/similar problem. Good luck to ya!

Answer (score 3):

As per [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\ . For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar")

You need to escape special character in selector or use name value attribute instead:

```
 jQuery("[id='{44C80A95-F3E4-40DA-9A97-50CADFFFED61}-{DD02CEA7-CC2B-4E4A-A725-86E82C6D11FC}']").attr("width","100%");
```

Answer (score 1):

By escaping the brackets ?

```
jQuery("#\{44C80A95-F3E4-40DA-9A97-50CADFFFED61\}-\{DD02CEA7-CC2B-4E4A-A725-86E82C6D11FC\}").attr("width","100%");
```

Source of inspiration: [jquery escape square brackets to select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404037/jquery-escape-square-brackets-to-select-element)

or better, see Milind Anantwar answer use `$("[id='anything here']")`

Comment: Tried this before, but I got the same error, don't know why.